# Copy x lines from a large file to a new file on mac

Tags: macos, file

I am looking for a quick and efficient way to extract x lines from a text file and save it to a new one. E.g. I have a 4GB text file (XML) and I just need to get an idea of the structure to parse them. No tools I tried (SublimeText2,TextWrangler,MacVim) was able to open the file, so my idea is to copy x lines to a new file and open that.

Hope someone can help me with that. Thanks and have a nice day!

Answer (score 11):

In a terminal, `head -100 yourFile` will give you the first 100 lines. Or `tail -100 yourFile` at the end.

```
head -1000 yourFile > littleFile
```

will put the first 1000 lines into littleFile and I suspect works on any size file you can create.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I generally do while investigating into huge log files. It is convenient to just take only the lines that is of interest into a separate file, which is effective specially when the log file is active and growing.

Step 1: grep for the pattern and get the line numbers of interest. Being in the logs folder...grep for the 'pattern'. The . searches the current directory and you can change accordingly or use other grep options.

```
grep -rnw . -e 'pattern'
```

./logfile.log:293910 // first occurrence of pattern

...

./logfile.log:294591 // last occurrence of pattern

So, the new file you want to create to investigate needs to have a few lines before the first occurrence of the pattern and a few lines after the last occurrence of the pattern. You create a separate file like this...

```
head -294800 ./logfile.log | tail -900 > test.log
```

Now you have a static 900 lines of the original log file that is lot more easier to work with. Hope this helps someone.

OR

within the vi/vim editor... you could just do like this where 100, 200 is the range

```
:100,200w test.log
```

OR

```
vim -c "100,200w test.log" -c wq logfile.log
```